# Comma separated values show with out float(.00) number in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am converting a PHP script into excel sheet using PHPExcel library I want comma separated values without floating number (`.00`).

I am using following script:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode
(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit("A1",(1111111),
PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

But when I convert the file in PHPExcel result show `1,111,111.00` but I want is `1,111,111` .

Is there any way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just specify the right format string (`'#,##0'`) by hand:

```
objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0');
```

From the [PHPExcel documentation](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Style/PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html#constFORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1):

> FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1 =  '#,##0.00'

This has two decimal places after the point, which you don't need.